# Finding enemy object in player's forward direction within a range

Tags: unity, c#

I would like to know the way by which I can find enemy objects tagged with "player" in a forward direction within a range say 3 units from the player.

Comment: I am not getting any clue about the logic. That is the reason I posted.  Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean within a 3 unit distance (ie. straight line), or a 3 unit wide range (ie. fanned out)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to cast a raycast forward like this: `

```
     Raycast hit;
     Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward);
     if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, RANGE)){
         if(hit.collider.tag == "Player"){
            ...
         }
```

`
RANGE = max range eg.3

Comment: Glad I helped. Would you mind up voting my answer and marking it as best if it worked for you

Comment: I did try to vote, but I think due to lack of reputation its not letting me do so.  Though I have accepted the answer.  Thanks again.